# Verify that no resource or JavaScript errors occurred

Tags: python, integration-testing, splinter

I need to verify, that no JavaScript exceptions or resource errors occur during our tests.

For phantomjs, there is for example an `onResourceError` event: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html

With splinter, is it possible, to have similar assertions? Like, for example, no resource error occurred after clicking the next button in a gallery, or no JavaScript exceptions occur after clicking a random option in the navigation bar.